# go cross platform compile ( x86_64 -> arm ) failed in link

Tags: linux, go, arm

I tried to cross compile from x86_64 (debian 10.8) but it failed with the following message

```
go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: running aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc failed: exit status 1
collect2: fatal error: cannot find 'ld'
compilation terminated.
```

Same code can be compiled successfully in x86_64. Any help is highly appreciated. Here are some details of the environment and command:
(1) command :

```
go build -i -v -trimpath -o targer.so -buildmode=plugin *.go
```

(2) The PATH yields the following choices:

```
   ld : gcc-linaro-4.9-2016.02-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld
  link: go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc : gcc-linaro-4.9-2016.02-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc
   go version go1.14.2 linux/amd64
```

(3) Related environment variables (I think)

```
GOARCH=arm64 CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=linux
```

```
/* no code sample */
```

Comment: Hey, could you please do proper formatting for the question you posted?

Comment: My Apology for the poor format. The current format is not the same when I type it, all the newlines are gone

Comment: I edited it. Does it look fine? You have to use code blocks for such cases.